# Did somebody connect to my facebook account?

Tags: passwords, facebook

I have a problem. I'm not sure, but I think that somebody found out a password to my Facebook account and sometimes logs in. Is there a way to find out whether it is true?

There must be something like Facebook connects log but I'm not sure if it would be helpful in my situation.

Comment: Settings>Security>Where youre logged in/sessions

Comment: If it's your home network, the IP address will be the same.  Time to change your password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i'm not wrong,

At **FAcebook** -> **settings** -> **security** ->  **Active Sessions**

There is a history of devices  connected to your account by date , with some useful info IP and city browser

SO you can switch to a difference browser, and if some one else log in will report with a browser that you don't use.

You can also disconnect them (unlink) from that panel too

Comment: Thanks for advice. I noticed one funny thing. When somebody connects to your facebook account, he can also remove his session from this log so you don't find out whether he was there :)

Comment: Wow..  that is huge security concern for me, make it notice to FB. why do I want a log history if I can just remove my self from it?

Comment: My fault... It is option "end activity" no delete... But I can see only current activities... I can't see history of log in's...  settings -> security -> Security Settings -> Where You're Logged In